# Sharepoint "quick link" is not uploading folders

Tags: sharepoint-online

Hi I am working on sharepoint communication site. I am using quick link to view some documents folder but now i cannot upload the folder itself, instead i have to choose only 1 selected file for the quick link. Please help

Comment: Question is not clear, could you please specify what permissions do you have on the site? and pls share the screenshot for a better understanding of the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

To add quick link in **Quick Launch** in Communication Site, follow below steps:

1. Go to Site Content --> Site Settings.
2. Select **Quick Launch** under **Look and Feel** section.
3. Select **New Navigation Link** if you want to create the link under any existing Heading or select **New Heading** to add new heading.
4. in URL textbox, provide url in format like:
    `siteUrl/LibraryName/FolderName`
5. in Description textbox, provide display text for that link.
6. Click OK.

It will add quick link in your Quick Launch section of communication site.

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to add the link of the folder in the quick link web part in the modern page?

If so, we cannot add the link of the folder in the quick link web part by default.

We only can add the link of the files.

It is by design.